# Receiving Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. when trying to authenticate a client App to a service App

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Here's my situation:

- I have a client web application (angular2) using msal-angular and a .net core 2.2 Web API service.
- I've registered both the client and the service in Azure AD. I added the client to the `knownClientApplications` array in the service app manifest.
- I'm able to successfully get tokens that appear to have all of the claims I need to properly authenticate

When trying to access an endpoint with the token retrieved by the client I'm seeing the following error in the debug output of my service:

`Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'client App ID'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'service App ID' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.`

I suspect that if I were to ditch the client App ID and just use the service App ID in the client as well things would probably work fine, but that doesn't seem correct.

**Should I just set validationParameters.ValidAudiences? If so, how do I do that?**
The pertinent section of my startup.cs shows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));
```

**Or, is there something I need to change in my client-side msal-angular configuration to tell it I need the token audience to reflect my service app id?**

Comment: Do you add the web api scope to `consentScopes` and acquire token for the api ? That seems you are using the wrong token . [Here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/34892e8d44d493df9754bc5692caebbccb451be3/lib/msal-angular/samples/MSALAngularDemoApp/src/app/app.module.ts) is code sample and [the document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) . Also do you consent the scope during authentication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope in you client web application should be `Application ID URL/.default`

```
api://691af574-47f6-4b8e-b544-b75ec4387938/TodoListService/.default
```

You can find this in web api application.

[image]